# ImageIcon(java.util.Optional<byte[]>)

Tags: java, java-swing, byte

Estoy intentando abrir/guardar una imagen desde un `jLabel` al escritorio pero me da el siguiente error en la sintaxis, ¿a qué se debe?

**Error en las líneas:**

```
ImageIcon fot = new ImageIcon(imagen);
salida.write(imagen);


no suitable constructor found for ImageIcon(java.util.Optional<byte[]>)
    constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(java.net.URL) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to java.net.URL)
    constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(java.awt.Image) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to java.awt.Image)
    constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(byte[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to byte[])
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**Código:**

```
public class GuardarImagenes extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JFileChooser seleccionado = new JFileChooser();
    Optional<byte[]> imagen;
    FileInputStream entrada;
    FileOutputStream salida;
    File archivo;

    public GuardarImagenes() {
        initComponents();
    }


    private Optional<byte[]> readFile(String path) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private void button_elegirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if(seleccionado.showDialog(null, "ABRIR ARCHIVO") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo = seleccionado.getSelectedFile();
            if(archivo.canRead()){
                if(archivo.getName().endsWith("jpg") || archivo.getName().endsWith("jpeg") || archivo.getName().endsWith("png") || archivo.getName().endsWith("gif")){
                    imagen = readFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
                    ImageIcon fot = new ImageIcon(imagen);
                    Icon icono = new ImageIcon(fot.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth(), label_foto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                    label_foto.setIcon(icono);
                    button_guardar.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecionne un archivo...");
                }
            }
        }
    }                                             

    public String GuardarImagen(File archivo, Optional<byte[]> imagen) {
        String respuesta = null;
        try (FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo)) {
            salida.write(imagen);
            respuesta = "La imagen se guardó con éxito.";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    private void button_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        if(seleccionado.showDialog(null, "GUARDAR IMAGEN") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo = seleccionado.getSelectedFile();
            if(archivo.getName().endsWith("jpg") || archivo.getName().endsWith("png") || archivo.getName().endsWith("gif")){
                String respuesta = GuardarImagen(archivo, imagen);
                if (respuesta != null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, respuesta);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar imagen.");
                }
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La imagen no tiene formato de imagen.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: new ImageIcon(imagen.get)